# Calculate: $\arg(i)+\arg(-1)$

Tags: complex-analysis, complex-numbers

Calculate $\arg(i)+\arg(-1)$:

(a) $\arg(-i) \quad$ (b) $\arg(1-i) \quad$ (c) $\arg(1+i) \quad$ (d) $\text{None}$

I found it $\arg(-i)$ but it's not correct, my teacher said.

Comment: To be perfectly clear, some authors define $\text{Arg}(z)$ to be a function from $\Bbb C$ to $(-\pi,\pi]$.  Others define it to be a function from $\Bbb C$ to $[0,2\pi)$.  How does *your* teacher/book define it?

Comment: At least check [Wolfy](http://m.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=arg%28i%29+%2B+arg%28-1%29) first.

Comment: She defines it from C to (-pi,pi]

Answer (score 2):

Well, $\arg(i)=\pi/2$ and $\arg(-1)=\pi,$ so $\arg(i)+\arg(-1)=?$ And which of the answers corresponds to this?